# Getting list of hyperlinks from an Excel worksheet with Perl Win32::OLE

Tags: perl, excel, hyperlink, ole

I want to change the path for a bunch of hyperlinks in an Excel spreadsheet.  After searching Google, I came across a [solutions](http://programming.itags.org/perl/91062/) to the problem of *adding* hyperlinks to spreadsheets, but not *changing* them.  Microsoft showed how to something close with VBA [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247507).

Since I want to edit every single hyperlink in my document, the key steps that I don't know how to solve are:

1. Get a list of hyperlink objects in Perl
2. Extract their addresses 1 by 1 and
3. Run a regular expression to make the path change
4. Store the updated path in the Hyperlink->object and repeat

I am new to using the OLE and am getting tripped up on (1). Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const "Microsoft Excel";

my $file_name = 'C:\path\to\spreadsheet.xlsx';
my $excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;});
$excel->{Visible} = 1;
my $workbook = $excel->Workbooks->Open($file_name);
my $sheet = $workbook->Worksheets('Sheet 1');
foreach my $link (in $sheet->Hyperlinks ) {
say $link->Address;
}
```

But this gives code the error:

> Win32::OLE(0.1709): GetOleEnumObject() Not a Win32::OLE::Enum object at C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib/Win32/OLE/Lite.pm line 167.
>   Can't call method "Hyperlinks" without a package or object reference at at script.pl line 14.

It's selecting the right worksheet, so I am not sure why it complains about an object reference. I tried several variations (Adding {} around Hyperlinks, removing the 'in', trying to store it as a list, as a hash, and as a reference to a hash) Can anyone give me some pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Should there be a space between 'Sheet' and '1'?  Excel by default names its sheets 'Sheet1' with no space.

Comment: Does your code really say `foreach my $link (in $sheet->Hyperlinks )`? I presume not, as that would compile as `$sheet->in->Hyperlinks` and a worksheet has no method `in`.

Comment: @Borodin "**`in(COLLECTION)`**: *If COLLECTION is an OLE collection object then in `$COLLECTION` returns a list of all members of the collection. This is a shortcut for `Win32::OLE::Enum-All($COLLECTION)`. It is most commonly used in a `foreach` loop*". I think the OP had to use `in( $sheet->Hyperlinks )`, but I've found `in` to be flaky. Or, put another way, I have problems when I use `in` which I have always been able to avoid by using an explicitly constructed `Win32::OLE::Enum` iterator.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks Sinan. So it's a *function* and needs exporting from `Win32::OLE` which the OP's question doesn't show.

Comment: @Borodin Correct, and you put it much more succinctly than my lengthy quotation and rambling commentary ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should set `$Win32::OLE::Warn=3` so your script will croak the moment something goes wrong. Second, I know you can't select sheets by name in older versions of Excel, although I do not know what things are like in the newest versions. Finally, I think you'll find it easier to use [Win32::OLE::Enum](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aOLE%3a%3aEnum).

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use warnings; use strict;

use Carp qw( croak );
use Path::Class;
use Try::Tiny;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
use Win32::OLE::Enum;
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

my $book_file = file($ENV{TEMP}, 'test.xls');
say $book_file;

my $excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;});
$excel->{Visible} = 1;

my $book = $excel->Workbooks->Open("$book_file");
my $sheet = get_sheet($book, 'Sheet with Hyperlinks');
my $links = $sheet->Hyperlinks;
my $it = Win32::OLE::Enum->new($links);

while (defined(my $link = $it->Next)) {
    my $address = $link->{Address};
    say $address;
    if ($address =~ s/example/not.example/) {
        $link->{Address} = $address;
        $link->{TextToDisplay} = "Changed to $address";
    }
}

$book->Save;
$book->Close;
$excel->Quit;

sub get_sheet {
    my ($book, $wanted_sheet) = @_;

    my $sheets = $book->Worksheets;
    my $it = Win32::OLE::Enum->new($sheets);

    while (defined(my $sheet = $it->Next)) {
        my $name = $sheet->{Name};
        say $name;
        if ($name eq $wanted_sheet) {
            return $sheet;
        }
    }

    croak "Could not find '$wanted_sheet'";
}
```

The workbook did contain a sheet with the name `"Sheet with Hyperlinks"`. Cell `A1` in that sheet contained `http://example.com` and `A2` contained `http://stackoverflow.com`.